# loopback model.find based on param from related model

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a problem with falowing situation:

```
Model 1: Guest - props {"slug":"string"}

Model 2: Project - props {"prefix":"string"}

Relation: Project has many guests
```

How to write remote method: `findGuestWithProject(prefix, slug)` that will return `guest` with `slug` (exact match but case insensitive) and related project with exact `prefix`?

Problems I encountered:

1. Initial filter return `Guests` with similar but not exact slug f.e. if I pass `"anna"` `.find` could return guests with slug `"anna-maria"`, so later on I need to check id slug is exactly the same.
2. Initial filter return `Guests` with different `project.prefix` so I need to do extra loop to find exact match.
3. I need to count iteration to return callback if not match found.

```js
  Guest.getGuestProject = function(prefix, slug, cb) {
    if (!prefix) return;
    var pattern = new RegExp(slug, "i");
     app.models.Project.findOne({
       "where": {"prefix": prefix}
     },(err, project) => {
      if (err) { throw err};
      if (!project) cb(null, null);
      return project.guests({
        "where": {"slug":  pattern },
        "include": {"relation": "project", "scope": {"include": {"relation": "rsvps"}}}
      }, (err, guests) => {
        if (guests.length === 0) cb(null, null)
         guests.forEach(guest => {
           if (guest.slug.toLowerCase() === slug.toLowerCase()) {
             cb(null, guest)
           }
        })
      })
     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1: Your regexp is checking for anything containing `slug`

For 2 and 3 I've just rewritten it. You haven't specified what db connector you are using (mongodb, mysql, postgres, etc) so I've written this example based on Postgresql, which is the one I usually use and one of the worst-case-scenarios, given that relational databases don't support filtering by nested properties. If you are using either Mongodb or Cloudant take a look at the example provided in https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html#filtering-nested-properties because this snippet could be simpler.

If this answer is not what you were looking for then I'll probably need more details. I'm also using promises instead of callbacks.

```
Guest.getGuestProject = function(prefix, slug) {
    const Project = Guest.app.models.Project;
    // First of all find projects with the given prefix
    return Project.find({
        where: {
            prefix: prefix
        },
        include: 'guests'
    }).then(projects => {
        projects.forEach(project => {
            let guests = project.guests();
            guests.forEach(guest => {
                // See if guest.slug matches (case-insensitive)
                if (guest.slug.match(new RegExp(slug, 'i'))) {
                    return guest;
                }
            });  
        });
    });  
};
```